# grails actionsubmit bypass jquery validation

Tags: jquery, grails

I have this cancel button. How can I bypass Jquery validation?

```
<g:actionSubmit value="Cancel" action="create"/>
```

Comment: Why are you using an actionSubmit to Cancel? You could use a regular link so that no JQuery valdiation will occure.

Comment: I want it look like a button.

Comment: You can style your link so that it looks like a button. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to jquery documentation, if you don't want the button to fire validation, just add a class called cancel. So, it is <
g:actionSubmit value="Cancel" class="cancel"/>