# How to call a controller method from a button in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I feel really stupid right now, but I can't seem to find an answer.

So I have a method which needs to be called EXACTLY once, and since this is only the experimental phase, I decided that a simple button should suffice. However, I can't seem to find out how to / if I can simply call the method from a button click.

The method is in home_controller.rb and the button is in index.html.erb

Any ideas? Or is this not something I can do?

Answer (score 25):

```
<%= form_tag home_action_path, method: :post do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Call Action' %>
<% end %>
```

could also use a link

```
<%= link_to 'Call Action', home_action_path, method: :post %>
```

or you can use button_to

```
<%= button_to 'Call Action', home_action_path, method: :post %>
```

in your routes

```
post 'home/action'
```

Comment: for routes in rails 6, it should be  post' homes/action' & path will be homes_action_path

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

Example shows you can do something like

```
<%= button_to "Some Button", :method=> "someButton" %>
```

Comment: what if the button is being generated by a external script. say for example stripe.js is generating "Pay with Card" button. How can I link this Pay with Card link to a method in my controller. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create a route for your action and call it that way. Forgive me, I'm not sure what your `home_controller.rb` is doing. If it is the controller for your home page, I believe a `pages_controller.rb` with a `home` method is more conventional for Rails.

If that were the case, and assuming the method you want to call is named `call_action`,

Your `pages_controller.rb` would look something like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  #...

  def call_action
    <<does something really nifty>>
  end

end
```

Your `config/routes.rb` would look like:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  #...

  resources :pages do
    collection do
      get :call_action
    end
  end

end
```

The link on your home page at `views/pages/home.html.erb` would look like this:

```
<%= link_to "Call Action", call_action_pages_path %>
```

You should run `rake routes` on your command line to make sure you have the correct route, then stick `_path` on the end of it.

If you want your link to be a button, you can [create a styled class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button) for that and append it to your link:

```
<%= link_to "Call Action", call_action_pages_path, class: "button" %>
```

Or wrap it in a styled class:

```
<div class="button">
  <%= link_to "Call Action", call_action_pages_path %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <%= button_to 'Invite a user', new_project_invite_path, method: :get, remote: true, class: 'btn primary' %>
```

If you don't want it to be an Ajax call then you can remove remote: true

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as adding *method*_*controller*_path to the HTML.
For instance, I have a route `filaments/new`, and to add a button that links to it from any view:
`<%= button_to "Add", new_filament_path, method: :get %>`