# Calling a method from a button submit action in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

First, I want to implement a simple, single input form method in the view of a Rails 4 file.

This form will need to create a new record in a table called `Points` after the user submits.

To set this up, in my **homeform.html.erb**, I have added a link with a post method to test ([following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243200/how-to-call-a-controller-method-from-a-button-in-rails-4)).

```
<%= link_to 'Call Action', points_path, method: :post %>
```

In my **PagesController**, I have a corresponding **Points** class:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def points

    def promo_points
      Point.create(user_id: 10, points: 500)
    end 
  end 
end
```

I am testing by creating a record with two hard coded attributes to see if it works. Finally, in my **Routes.rb** file, I added:

```
  post 'points/promo_points'
```

With the hope that when I click the link to post in the view, this will execute the `promo_points` method and generate that new record.

That is not happening, as I am receiving an error for `No route matches [POST] "/points"`. Given the simplicity of this form, is there an easier way to call the `promo_points` method from the form helper in Rails every time the user clicks the link or submits?

Answer (score 1):

```
post '/points', to: 'pages#points', as: :points
```

**UPD:**

```
  def points

    def promo_points
      Point.create(user_id: 10, points: 500)
    end 
  end
```

By this way you only define `promo_points` method but does not call it.

It will be good if you move your `promo_points` method to `Point` class:

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.promo_points!
    create(user_id: 10, points: 500)
  end
end
```

And call it in your controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def points
    Point.promo_points!
  end 
end
```

Comment: The page now loads; however, it does not post using the `promo_points` action from the method in my Pages Controller. Maybe it's because we are not calling it specifically? To test, I am running `Point.last` and it's not creating a new record. Any ideas?

Comment: @darkginger Updated my answer