# appearance: none cross-browser solution

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, cross-browser, opera

I'm tryin gto style a `button` HTML5 element and I see that there is an automatic appearance applied to these elements. Reading on blogs I found this solution:

```
.thing {
   -webkit-appearance: value;
   -moz-appearance:    value;
   appearance:         value;
}
```

But then I [checked](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp) and it seems this does not work on IE neither on Opera. How can I make this work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This might be similar to what you're trying to do:

[How do I make an html link look like a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button)

Unfortunately there's no real way of simulating a button in IE or Opera, they just don't support it. You could do some CSS fiddling to make `.thing` look like a button, but because buttons appear differently on each browser, it might look change having an IE button in an Opera window. Your best option is probably to put an actual button on the page.

If you gave us some code or any idea of what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to give you more help.

Comment: I'm just trying to have a button completely free of browser styling. I just checked and border: 0; is the answer.