# Invoke paritcular ActionResult using button click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, buttonclick, actionresult

When I click on button I need to invoke ResetValues method in controller. But am able to invoke the DocDetails method.
Can anyone help me out!!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DocDetails", "FormAdmin", FormMethod.Get))
{
//some other controls and logic related to that
 @{ Html.BeginForm("ResetValues", "FormAdmin", FormMethod.Post);}


                        <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ResetValues","FormAdmin")'" >Search2</button>

                      @{ Html.EndForm();}

}
```

Comment: you should look into jquery ajax calls http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am not ready to use ajax calls. Any other help is appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Do not embed one form inside another.

Instead, you can use [`@Html.ActionLink()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx) to create a link that redirects the user to a different action, then [style the link to look like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button):

[Edited to show usage without nesting forms]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DocDetails", "FormAdmin", FormMethod.Get)) {

  //some other controls and logic related to that
  @Html.ActionLink("Search2", "ResetValues", new {},  new { @class = "button" })
}
```

Comment: I have tried but no luck. Error message: http 404. Page not found.

Comment: Please try it without nested forms.  The link renders to an HTML anchor element, so it can be placed anywhere on the page, even outside the form.  If you are getting 404 error then the route to the action or the action parameters may be incorrect.  You can add action parameters in the third argument.  Does your action require a parameter?