# how to convert link to look of command button

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a field (in a GridView):
     
                            
                                     
                                 
                                 
If I change asp:LinkButton to asp:Button the code behind does not work. I want the appearance of the control to look like a button not a link but otherwise I want it to function as it does now. What should I do?

Comment: CSS is there for such tasks.

Comment: Simple solution is best. Copied style of internet and it worked great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can make LinkButton look like button using CSS:

```
.button {
font: bold 11px Arial;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
color: #333333;
padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-right: 1px solid #333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

See previous discussion on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button)