# Create button that functions like link and opens a new popup through a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function that creates a new popup window.

```
function newTab(center, section, tab) {
    currentItem.numWindows += 1;
    var title = "Window #" + currentItem.numWindows;
    var tabsObject = [center, section, tab];
    currentItem.windows[currentItem.numWindows] = window.open('popup.php', title, toolbar = 0, menubar = 0, navigationbar = 0);
    currentItem.windows[currentItem.numWindows].variable = tabsObject;
}
```

I want to create a button that looks like a button but acts like a link. To clarify, when the user right clicks on the button I need it to open up the standard browser options like "open in new window" or "open in new tab".

Instead of this leading to a standard "otherpage.html" I need it to call my JS function (which in turn creates the popup).

I have searched and I keep finding examples that look like a link but don't act like a link.

I have tried IameLemon's suggestion,

```
<a onclick="someFunction();"><button type="button">Text of Some Page</button></a>
```

this code works however it does not allow the user to right click and access the standard options that come with a link (the ability to open in a new tab or window)

Thanks!

Comment: why cant you use `<a>`?

Comment: Did you consider adding a link itself, and adding appropriate CSS to make it appear like a button?

Comment: Am I missing something?  What's the question?  Where are you stuck?  Does this code not work in some way?

Comment: I have used <a> in multiple ways. The issue is that I need the new page to be launched by the javascript function and the ability for the user to right click and open as a tab or window.

Comment: what did you try..? could you please show us what you have tried so far..and also please explain clearly the problem that you are facing..

Comment: use the `onclick` attribute for `<a>` to call the javascript function..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an html link look like a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button)

Comment: _"and the ability for the user to right click and open as a tab or window"_ ... and only using a link will get you that, for buttons browsers don't offer those options. So use a link, and _format_ it to look like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Apply css styling to an anchor.

```
<a href='function();' style='whateverfloatsYourBoat'>value</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a button within a link:

```
<a href='newtab();'><button type=button>button text</button></a>
```

Comment: Might want to add `<button type="button">` so that it doesn't submit any parent forms.

Comment: Same as with the other answer - that would be invalid HTML.

Comment: @CBroe what does that mean?

Comment: html validation rules disallow a button inside of an anchor

Answer (score 0):

Stealing from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button).

Why not just wrap a button in a link?  Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gsx5Lbj/) as well.

```
<a onclick="someFunction();"><button type="button">Text of Some Page</button></a>
```

Comment: _"Why not just wrap a button in a link?"_ - because that would be invalid HTML.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use CSS. Below will make a link look like a button. i.e., if you right click it, it will give you option to open in new tab, etc.

.SSSBUTTON_CONFIRMLINK {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: rgb(64, 111, 53);
    background-color: rgb(222,235,181);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: rgb(142, 203, 98);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(114, 175, 69);
    border-left-color: rgb(142, 203, 98);
    border-right-color: rgb(114, 175, 69);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: solid;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}

<a class="SSSBUTTON_CONFIRMLINK" href="#top">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: It will make a link look like a button.