# NavigateUrl and Eval in a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have this line of code which uses a hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink style="text-decoration:none" runat="server" Text="View Order" NavigateUrl='<%# "OrderDetails2.aspx?oID=" + Eval("oID") %>'>/asp:HyperLink>
```

Works perfectly fine but when I try to use a button to do the same thing (since I have to use an OnClick method), it doesn't allow me to use NavigateUrl and Eval in it. Any alternative methods?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do.

If you are trying to add a link to another page, just use `asp:hyperlink` but [use CSS to make it look like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button).

If you really do want a button with a server-side click event, you can add the following to the end of the click event handler:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("OrderDetails2.aspx?oID={0}", oID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because [asp:button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a property called NavigateUrl, its only a valid property for an hyperlink.

You can use JavaScript `click` event for an asp:hyperlink.