# button href not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<a href="signUp.html"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitSignUp" >Sign Up</button></a>
```

Why does this not work? I have a different page called signUp and on-click of the sign-up button, I want it to go to the signUp page.

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: If you want your a tag to look like a button you must use CSS.
[a tag like button with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button)
[more ways to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Look the following link:
[a tag like button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Look the following link:
[a tag like button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Give a try to the following link:
[a tag like button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not place `<button>` inside `<a>` element as `<button>` consumes  mouse events preventing `<a>` element click generation.

So try just this

```
<a href="signUp.html" class="btn btn-primary submitSignUp">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

to have the same result I would suggest you to change your code to this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary submitSignUp" href="signUp.html">Sign Up</a>
```