# links are not working in mozilla and IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to attach a button to link, the link is working fine in google chrome, but its not working in IE and mozilla, is there anything to do about it.

```
   <button class="button1"><a href="https://cleartax.in/s/gstr2" target="_blank">GSTR-2 RETURN FILING</a></button>
```

Comment: Don't wrap the link in a `button` tag.  `Button` tags have semantic meaning that is overriding your link.

Comment: So how do i have to change code, do i have to end link tag after closing button tag?

Comment: If you want to have a button-link I would suggest to make a link looks like a button. It's a standard approach. There is a good answer about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/710108/3710672

Comment: Why do you even have a `button` tag around your `a` tag? Remove it completely, and use styles / css to make the `a` tag look the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way if you no way without `button`:

```
<button class="button1" onclick="window.open('https://cleartax.in/s/gstr2')">GSTR-2 RETURN FILING</button>
```

Comment: Ugh.  Why resort to javascript just to make a link look like a button? This is **not** the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes I know the best practice as well. Seems he need keep the button as a mandatory for design or DOM manipulation, that's why I not suggested to use link and go his way. Surely my approach also not invalid indeed anyway if you check with validator engine. I just followed the context.