# This tags HTML don't work on IE and Mozilla

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, mozilla

I try this html code on Google Chrome and works. But on Mozilla and IE11 don't works link. Why? Thanks all

```
<button>
 <span>
  <a href="/home">Home</a>
 </span>
</button>
```

Comment: "don't work" means what exactly?. Is this in any way related to Angular?

Comment: Because it is invalid HTML - you can not nest other “interactive” elements such as a link into a button.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It is the html of an angular component. When clicking the button this does not respond. In chrome it makes the redirection towards home.

Comment: @CBroe how should the code be? Thanks

Comment: It should be a simple link. Remove `button`.

Comment: @CBroe I tried, but the design is not the same when I use styles

Comment: I think you should check what the DOM actually contains as first debugging step. There is probably some HTML stripped because it is not valid HTML. Angular should cause an error for invalid HTML though.

Comment: _“but the design is not the same when I use styles”_ - well then _change_ the styles accordingly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button

Answer (score 1):

> But on Mozilla and IE11 don't works link. Why?

Because it is invalid HTML - you can not nest other “interactive” elements such as a link into a button.

[HTML5, 4.10.6. The button element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-button-element):

> Content model:
>   Phrasing content, but there must be no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-2) descendant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to do something like this.

**Code**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home/button>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not working because it is not allowed [w3 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

is not allowed inside 
Better to make a input with the href