# How to make my button shows in the buttom of the page the href?

Tags: php, html, forms, button

Well , i got a button on this form

```
echo " <td><form action='action.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='itemid' name='itemid' value='". $row["name"] ."'/>
            <input type='hidden' id='seller' name='seller' value='". $row["player"] ."'/>
         <input  type='submit' value='Buy'/>
       </form></td>";
```

This is the button

```
             <input  type='submit' value='Buy'/>
```

Is it possible to make the button shows down in the buttom of the page the direct link ?

[image: Just like this example]

Comment: keep this form at the bottom of the page

Comment: where exaclty ? under what ?

Comment: do you want to display this form in the footer section of the page, if so, keep this form in footer

Comment: and does the button move to the footer ? do i move only the `<form> </form>` ?

Comment: keep this entire code in footer

<form action='action.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='itemid' name='itemid' value='". $row["name"] ."'/>
            <input type='hidden' id='seller' name='seller' value='". $row["player"] ."'/>
         <input  type='submit' value='Buy'/>
       </form>

Comment: lol i don't want to move the button i only want to make the href link shows up like in the picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an html link look like a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You will have to use the `<a>` tag, style it as a button and submit the form via Javascript.