# Scroll up button without javascript

Tags: html, css

I want this, but without javascript:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_to_top

And also I want the button to lead me to the element h1 id="bob"

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #btn {
         display: none;
         position: fixed;
         bottom: 10px;
         right: 10px;
         z-index: 99;
         font-size: 15px; 
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         background-color: gray;
         color: darkgray;
         cursor: pointer; 
         padding: 15px;
         border-radius: 4px;
         }
         #btn:hover {
         background-color: white;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="#top" id="btn"></button>
      <h1 id="top">Hoy!</h1>
      <pre>
.
.
.
<!-- here I put a lot of dots to make the page scrollable -->
.
.
.
</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SO use a link, not a button

Comment: @epascarello he will face this problem because of not using a link, but now he doesn't know how to show the button (or the link whatever) when the user scrolls down. I think he also wants to hide the element when the user scrolls to the very top

Comment: But I want a button. Can't I have a button?

Comment: @Twinsen you can use a link (anchor) and give it the button styling with css, or you can use a button but you need to use a link inside it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button

Comment: you can't see ur button because of your CSS `display:none`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, terrible formatting in the question.

1. Make sure your links are clickable.
2. Make your html/css code a snippet, which would solve the code formatting issue and make people happier and more willing to help you out.  Using a **Css Beautifier**/**HTML Beautifier** also helps the positivity of the post.
3. Show what you've previously done, this question could've easily been answered by yourself with a [W3 guide on smooth scrolling](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1)
4. You also can't see your button because of your css `display:none` on `#btn`.

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
     height:1000px;
}
 #top{
}
 #middle {
     margin-top:500px;
}
 #btn {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 10px;
     right: 10px;
     z-index: 99;
     font-size: 15px;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     background-color: gray;
     color: darkgray;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 15px;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
 #btn:hover {
     background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 id="top">Hoy!</h1>
    <h2 id="middle">Middle!</h2>
    
    <a href="#top" id="btn"></button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini I think you're tripping dawg.  I copied the css from the question, it's not a copy and paste from someone else's answer.

Comment: edit your answer so I can revise my downvote.

Comment: That's the proper answer. Thank you very much! Sorry about the link. I couldn't manage to correct it even editing the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anchor tag with the `href` attribute. For example, you have the following basic HTML structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
  <!--lot of sections here -->

  <a href="#body">Back to Top!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You only need to set an `id` to an element, then with your anchor tag set the attribute `href` with the value of an "#" followed by the `id` of your top element.

Comment: No need to add body there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a `<a href="#"></a>` tag and set the *href* to #. This will get you on top of the page.

```css
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

article {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ff0000
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<a href="#">Top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
[code example](https://codepen.io/mohamedwr/pen/xxdJVVp)

The link has the style of a button and only shows when the user scrolls down and it hides when the user scrolls to the very top.
The trick here is to override the link with another hidden link but with an absolute position.

In order for this to **work**:

1. The two links should have exactly the same style and contents.
2. The hidden link should have the same background as the body.
3. The hidden link should have text color property the same as the background-color property of the body.
4. The hidden link should be positioned as absolute.

**Note**: you can use smooth scrolling (scroll-behavior: smooth;) to make it scroll with a simple animation

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  height: 5000px;
}

#top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkgray;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.hidden-btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<a class="btn" href="#top"></a>
<a class="btn hidden-btn"></a>
<h1>The top is here.</h1>
```